# “Deleted” from array still exists

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to delete some information from an array, however when I go to search for the deleted thing it still shows up.

I have tried this code:

```
function removeperson() {

    var search = prompt("Type in someone's name to remove them.");
    while(!found && i < people.names.length) {
        if(people.names[i] == search){
            found = true;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
    if(found){
            people.names.splice[i, 1];
            people.emails.splice[i, 1];
            people.phonenums.splice[i, 1];
            alert("Person successfully removed!");
            found = false;
    } else {
            alert("That person is not here or has already been deleted.");
            found = false;
    }
    i = 0;

}
```

However, when I use my search function to search for the deleted thing, it still appears. The full code is available here: https://js.do/nioiluc/321017

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`splice` method it's not being executed. Change to

```
people.names.splice(i,1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you are using slice with square brackets. That doesn't invoke the function. You need to use round brackets.
Second, in findperson, you must assign found to false before the while loop.

Please see the improved version at https://js.do/code/323115

Regards.